# How to Get Error Details From MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I am calling a mysql stored procedure using PDO in PHP

```
try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$name_db", $user_db, $pass_db);    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('CALL sp_user(?,?,@user_id,@product_id)');    
    $stmt->execute(array("user2", "product2"));    
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    $errors = $stmt->errorInfo();
    if($errors){
        echo $errors[2];
    }else{
        /*Do rest*/
    }

}catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

that return below error because the name of the field in insert query was given wrong

```
Unknown column 'name1' in 'field list'
```

So i want to know if this is possible to get detailed error information something like:-

```
Unknown column 'Tablename.name1' in the 'field list';
```

that could tell me what column of which table is Unknown.

Comment: Do you have `name1` column in several table?

Comment: the actual column name is name but i changed it to name1 in my stored procedure intentionally to fetch errors. I want to retrieve detailed error information like Unknown column 'Tablename.name1' in the 'field list'; instead of just Unknown column 'name1' in the 'field list';

Answer (score 0):

while creating the pdo connection, pass options like error mode and encoding:
The PDO system consists of 3 classes: PDO, PDOStatement & PDOException.  The **PDOException** class is what you need for error handling.

Here is an example:

```
try
{
    // use the appropriate values …
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $login, $password);
    // any occurring errors wil be thrown as PDOException
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $ps = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `fruits` WHERE `type` = ?");
    $ps->bindValue(1, $_GET['type']);
    $ps->execute();
    $ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    $text = "";
    foreach ($ps as $row)
    {
         $text .= $row . "<br>";
    }
    // a function or method would use a return instead
    echo $text;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // apologise
    echo '<p class="error">Oops, we have encountered a problem, but we will deal with it. Promised.</p>';
    // notify admin
    send_error_mail($e->getMessage());
}
// any code that follows here will be executed
```

Comment: That could not help as now i get error "Error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name1' in 'field list'" after adding that line in my code. I want to fetch the table name too in the error so that i could know which table's column is Unknown. So i want to fetch the error something like "Unknown column 'Tablename.name1' in the 'field list';"

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be helpful for me.  "error_log" prints to the php error log but you can replace with whatever way you'd like to display the error.

```
} catch (PDOException $ex){
    error_log("MYSQL_ERROR"); //This reminds me what kind of error this actually is
    error_log($ex->getTraceAsString()); // will show the php file line (and parameter 
                                        // values) so you can figure out which
                                        // query/values caused it
    error_log($ex->getMessage());  // will show the actual MYSQL query error 
                                   // e.g. constraint issue
}
```

p.s. I know this is a bit late but maybe it can help someone.